# How to set limited number of files upload in asp.net multiple file upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the multiple file upload in `Asp.net` with `c#`

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" runat="server" />
```

I want to validate client side on uploading that the selection of file must be 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ValidateFile2(){
    var fileCount = document.getElementById('FileUpload2').files.length;
    if(fileCount > 10) // Selected images with in 10 count
    {
       alert("Please select only 10 images..!!!");
       return false;
    }
    else if(fileCount <= 0) // Selected atleast 1 image check
    {
       alert("Please select atleat 1 image..!!!");
       return false;
    }

    return true;  // Good to go
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvLAc/93/)

Comment: its not working i have selected 13 images and its just show no of count of file as you mention in alert message  Please select only 10 images..!!! this message is now firing

Comment: i dont know how its showing correct ans even i checked in your mention fiddle

Answer (score 2):

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" **ClientIDMode**="Static" multiple="multiple" runat="server"/> 

**JQuery solution:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#FileUpload2').change(function () {
            var files = $(this)[0].files;
            if (files.length != 6) {
                alert("Six files have to be selected at a time!");
            }
            else
            {
                submit();//your custom method to submit the form
            }
        });
    });
```

Note: I could use the ID as selector as I have set the ClientIDMode property to static. This property was introduced from .NET 4.0 [[Click here to know more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)]. Alternatively, you may also use the class name for the control as selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>  
    <input type="file" ID="fuPhoto" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="button" ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload"  Enabled="false" />
    <label ID="myLabel"  ForeColor="#CC0000" />
</div> 
</form>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#fuPhoto').change(          
        function () {  
   var files = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;
    alert(files.length )
        //var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg'];
if (files.length>6) {
                    $('#btnUpload').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#myLabel').html("limit upto six");
                }
                else {
                    $('#btnUpload').attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#myLabel').html(" ");
                } 
            })  
    }) 
</script>
```

updated Code below

```
$(function () { 
       var files = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;
        alert(files.length )
    if (files.length>6) {
                        $('#btnUpload').attr("disabled", true);
                        alert("limit upto six");
                    }
                    else {
                       //nothing
                    } 
        })
```

Comment: I have added sample code only.. Did you replaced your original Ids under script?

Comment: I guess your ids will be different under browser. Did you added client id i.e <%=FileUpload2.ClientID%> under script?

Comment: i have put #FileUpload2 on the script

Comment: you mean to say like  $(<%=FileUpload2.ClientID%>).change(...)  ?

Comment: i have updated code under updated section. Pls check

Comment: Thanks for reply Amit - when i used to the updated code a js popup is open with the value '0' on page load.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code behind and do something like

`if(FileUpload2.Count < 6)
    {
    //Error
    }
    else
    {
    //OK
    }`

you can also use a bit of JavaScript on the page to do the validation

`

```
function Validate() {
    var f = document.getElementById("fu");

    if(f.files.length < 6)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}        
</script>`
```

and on the button click event set `OnClientClick="Validate();"`

Answer (score 0):

> Try Below in code behind,

```
 if (FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count > 2) 
 {
    //error will show if file number more than 2
 }
 else
 {
    //will proceed with uploading if file count not more than 2
 }
```